# What is meaning of 'method' in method.carrier_code in Magento 2

Tags: magento, knockout.js, magento2, knockout-2.0

This question is related with reference to Magento 2 File: app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

I am Struggling to find out the meaning of word 'method' in ***value: method.carrier_code***

See the exact code script below:

```
<!--ko ifnot: ($parent.rates().length == 1)-->
<input type="radio" 
       data-bind="value: method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                  checked: $parent.isSelected,
                  attr: {
                     'id': 's_method_' + method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                    },
                click: $parent.selectShippingMethod"
       class="radio"/>
<!--/ko-->
```

You can find the complete code in the following path

```
app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
```

OR,

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`

Any Help or the direction to proceed on it will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Alternate File path : vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html